# TransactionScope needs DTC enabled in C# MVC

Tags: .net, transactions, entity-framework-6, transactionscope, msdtc

We are using RDS (Amazon Relational Database Service) for our db . we have some sp s which called in a transactionScope. we ahve Customized ExecutionStrategy for our DBConfig like this

```
public class MpDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MpDbConfiguration()
        {
            //SetExecutionStrategy(
            //    "System.Data.SqlClient", () => new MpExecutionStrategy(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));

            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy
                ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
                : new MpExecutionStrategy(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));
        }
//.....
}
```

SuspendExecutionStrategy is set to True when we have user transaction (related article made me use this defaultStrategy : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic)

Issue : I have this issue when I run the transactions like this

```
   using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
                {

                    if (entity != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.EmailAddress))
                    {
                        ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBankingService>().UnRegister(RequestContext.Current, entity);
                    }

                    Data.Configuration.MpDbConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = true;
                    Context.Current.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DeleteAccountByEmailAddress @usertodelete",
                                                               new SqlParameter("usertodelete", emailAddress));
                    scope.Complete();
                    Data.Configuration.MpDbConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = false;
                }
//....
```

This SP is a very big transaction but uses JUST one database . **The error I get is to Enable DTC. my question is WHY I NEED DTC**

> The underlying provider failed on Open.  Network access for
>   Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please
>   enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC
>   using the Component Services Administrative tool.

Actually these terms are pretty new for me, but based on a search I found out DTC is just used when we have Distributed Transactions. In out case, we dont have it .

Comment: DTC can also get invoked when there are multiple concurrent (nested) ambient transactions in the same context, or when one ambient transaction calls down to multiple data sources; is any of the code that *calls* this creating a `TransactionScope`? Does `UnRegister` talk to a database? Also, if you're only performing one SQL operation - *why use `TransactionScope`?* - perhaps just use a regular transaction - or, since you seem to be using a stored procedure - just make the SP work in an atomic way, perhaps using a transaction internally (and no transaction at the caller)

Comment: @MarcGravell UnRegister function is another call, to external service , and uses the database from our side .its not multiple data sources as far as I know

Comment: @MarcGravell  Just for my understanding , transactionScope doesnt always need DTC enabled. just when it find multiple datasources or connections .Is that correct?

Comment: The requirements here depend on the RDBMS and the specific version of the database server, and the OS of the client, and the .NET Framework version that you're using. It is *possible* to not use DTC for two sequential but not concurrent connections to the *same* data source, but: anything more complex than that will usually need DTC, and on down-level *anything*, then even two sequential (not concurrent) connections might need DTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution might be to use the legacy type of transactions instead of transaction Scope. apparently a service there maybe use another context .I also added try catch to rollback the transaction in case of any exception.

*Thanks @MarcGravell for the hints.*

```
   using (var dbContextTransaction = Context.Current.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                     //--- the code run inside the transaction 
                        Context.Current.SaveChanges();
                        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                       //....
                    }
                 }
```